# powershell v2 remoting - How do you enable unencrypted traffic

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a powershell v2 script that I'd like to run against a remote server.  When I run it, I get the error :

> Connecting to remote server failed
>   with the following error message : The
>   WinRM client cannot process the
>   request. Unencrypted traffic is
>   currently disabled in the client
>   configuration. Change the client
>   configurati on and try the request
>   again. For more information, see the
>   about_ Remote_Troubleshooting Help
>   topic.

I looked at the online help for about _ Remote_Troubleshooting, but it didn't point me towards how to enable unecrypted traffic.  Below is the script that I'm using that is causing me problems.

Note: I have already run Enable-PSRemoting on the remote machine to allow it to accept incoming requests.
I have tried to use a session option variable, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
$key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds"
Set-ItemProperty $key ConsolePrompting True

$tvar = "password"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $tvar -asPlainText –force
$username="domain\username"
$mySessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -NoEncryption 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

invoke-command -filepath C:\scripts\RemoteScript.ps1  -sessionoption $mySessionOption -authentication digest -credential $credential -computername RemoteServer
```

How do I enable unencrypted traffic?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

AllowEncrypted is defined on the client end, via the WSMAN: drive. You must be running powershell.exe (or powershell_ise.exe) as an elevated process.

```
ps> cd WSMan:\localhost\Client
ps> dir
Name                      Value
----                      -----
NetworkDelayms            5000
URLPrefix                 wsman
AllowUnencrypted          false
Auth
DefaultPorts
TrustedHosts
```

You would change it like so (after changing to the directory above):

```
Set-Item .\allowunencrypted $true
```

Hope this helps,

- Oisin

Comment: Same problem here, even after doing what you said, still throwing same error. any idea?

Comment: @unruledboy Look again - does it really say " Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the _client_ configuration" ?

Answer (score 12):

You probably will need to set the AllowUnencrypted config setting in both the Client and the Service.  The Service setting has to be changed in the remote server using the following:

```
set-item -force WSMan:\localhost\Service\AllowUnencrypted $true
```

And don't forget to also enable Digest Authorization:

```
set-item -force WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Digest $true
```

Comment: Why would you need to enable Digest Authorization?

Comment: Oh, silly me! It's to allow the system to digest the new settings, of course.

Comment: I appreciate your IT humor @x0n

Answer (score 3):

You can allow unencrypted traffic on the client with the following command (execute it on the client):

```
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

To verify, you can get the whole config (client and service) with this command:

```
winrm get winrm/config
```

Be aware that each machine has two configs (one for being a client, one for beeing a server). To allow unencrypted traffic on the server, execute the following command on the server:

```
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
enable-wsmancredssp –role server
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter `AllowUnencryptedTraffic` is under `GPO`, you can set it through registrar:

```
$RegPath = 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client'
$RegUnencryptedTraffic = 'AllowUnencryptedTraffic'
$RegValue = '1'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name $RegUnencryptedTraffic -Value $RegValue
```