# PowerShell remote command fail because of unencrypted traffic

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

The following codes run:

```
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        string runasUsername = "USERNAME";
        string runasPassword = "PASSWORD";

        string liveIdconnectionUri = "http://EXCHANGE_SERVER/PowerShell";

        foreach (char x in runasPassword)
        {
            password.AppendChar(x);
        }

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(runasUsername, password);

        // Set the connection Info
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo((new Uri(liveIdconnectionUri)), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
        credential);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic; //AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

        // create a runspace on a remote path
        // the returned instance must be of type RemoteRunspace

        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

        command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
        command.AddParameter("Identity", "first.last");
        command.AddParameter("Alias", "Fist Last");

        powershell.Commands = command;
        try
        {
            // open the remote runspace
            runspace.Open();
            // associate the runspace with powershell
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
            var result = powershell.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // dispose the runspace and enable garbage collection
            runspace.Dispose();
            runspace = null;
            // Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free
            // up any resources.
            powershell.Dispose();
            powershell = null;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.Read();
```

Exceptions throws:

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
>   The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is
>   currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client
>   configuration and try the request again. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I already set Basic Auth, allow unecrypted traffic.

I tried solution here [powershell v2 remoting - How do you enable unencrypted traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469791/powershell-v2-remoting-how-do-you-enable-unecrypted-traffic) , no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, struggled a for long time, kept changing possible combinations, and finally works with this:

The `AuthenticationMechanism` should be `AuthenticationMechanism.Default`, not `AuthenticationMechanism.Basic` (It's weird).

The final working version is:

```
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        string runasUsername = "USERNAME";
        string runasPassword = "PASSWORD";

        string liveIdconnectionUri = "http://EXCHANGE_SERVER/PowerShell";

        foreach (char x in runasPassword)
        {
            password.AppendChar(x);
        }

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(runasUsername, password);

        // Set the connection Info
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo((new Uri(liveIdconnectionUri)), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
        credential);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default; //AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

        // create a runspace on a remote path
        // the returned instance must be of type RemoteRunspace

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

        command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
        command.AddParameter("Identity", "MAIL_USER_ID_HERE");

        powershell.Commands = command;
        try
        {
            // open the remote runspace
            runspace.Open();
            // associate the runspace with powershell
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
            var result = powershell.Invoke();
            if (result.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("sucessful!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("failed!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // dispose the runspace and enable garbage collection
            runspace.Dispose();
            runspace = null;
            // Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free
            // up any resources.
            powershell.Dispose();
            powershell = null;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Basic is a clear-text(unencrypted) authentication similar to when you get a popupbox on a website. Default for WS-man is using Kerberos(encrypted) in domain or negotiate between non-domain computers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  It should also be pointed out that, for the Virtual directory on the EXCHANGE_SERVER hosting the PowerShell instance, you should configure the **SSL settings** to "Accept" but not "Require SSL" in IIS Manager, assuming you still have the default self-signed certificate installed on the server.  That plus the "**AuthenticationMechanism.Default**" setting got rid of the myriad exceptions I encountered at the line:

```
runspace.Open();
```

Also, if you want to unit test this locally, you should [Install the Exchange Management Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232090%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) on your desktop.

...or, if you don't have Windows 8, try this approach:  [PowerShell Managed code in Exchange 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/03/25/how-to-migrating-exchange-2007-powershell-managed-code-to-work-with-exchange-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

AuthenticationMechanism.Default worked for me but lead to another error message...

> The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication
>   may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the
>   transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and
>   explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure
>   TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not
>   be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run
>   the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Note that EXCHANGE_SERVER must be a DNS name, not an IP address like I was using.    I also had to set the AllowUnencrypted config setting on both the client and the Exchange server.  See the link below for details on that setting.

[powershell v2 remoting - How do you enable unencrypted traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469791/powershell-v2-remoting-how-do-you-enable-unencrypted-traffic)